# Get country statistics using Iterate Feature Selection in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm using night light data from the NOAA and I want to generate statistics on luminosity for each country, ie what is the mean pixel value for a country. I have been following this guide: http://economics.mit.edu/files/8945

This guide worked for one country and now, starting from clipping the countries, I would like to use the Model Builder in ArcMap to do the same thing for each country using the iterate feature selection. Here is what I've tried so far, which is to follow the above guide and add those tools in the model builder:

[image]

The "countries_erase" is a layer containing boundaries where I have selected the "Name" as the field. "F182013" is the night light raster file. From there on the I wish/tried to create a fishnet and clip it to the night light data. Finally I tried to use the "Zonal Statistics as Table" to obtain the statistic and then merge all values for each country into a dataset that can be loaded to Stata.

I've tried running the model but it fails midway through and since I'm a complete novice I don't know how to fix it or if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: I don't understand why you need an iterative model insteadd of  applying the "zonal stat as a table" on all countries at once

Answer (score 2):

Iterate Features is meant to iterate features (i.e. feature class) within a geodatabase or a feature dataset. You need to change the iterator and use [iterate rows](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000010000000.htm) instead.

If it still fails, please provide a better image of your model, since it is too small. Yet your work flow sounds solid, except the iterator.

Comment: I changed the iterator to rows instead but it failed at the first clip. Pardon the small image.Here is a large image of the current work flow http://i.imgur.com/Rj6Ncyq.png

Comment: I second providing a better image. It is difficult to read all of the steps in the model.

Comment: try extract by mask instead of clip. That is used to "clipping" rasters with polygon or raster mask

Comment: dof1985 and @juturna In questions images are automatically resized to 600 pixels. The full resolution image is available though - you can right-click the image, get the address, and paste it to a new browser tab. Alternatively some browsers (not Internet Explorer) have a context menu item when you right-click to open or view the full-size image in a new window. Unfortunately SE doesn't code things such that the image in the question links to the full-size - a feature that has been requested/discussed many times before.